# Cómo saber el tipo de dato que pasas por una superclase

Tags: java, clase, objeto, herencia, genericos

Quiero saber cómo se puede hacer para saber qué tipo de dato estoy pasando por `<T extends Transportable>`. Tengo este código en el que la clase `Contenedor` se le puede pasar un tipo Contenedor, Generico, SerVivo o Toxico y según el tipo se lo pongo de nombre. La variable `private T contenedor` que he creado ignorarla porque solo era una prueba.

```
public class Contenedor<T extends Transportable> extends Transporte implements Generico, Transportable{

    private double volumen;
    private T contenedor;
    Stack<T> stk = new Stack<T>();

    public Contenedor(double volumen){
        super(volumen,"Contenedor de ");
        this.volumen = volumen;
        String tipoTransportable = "";
        if(this.contenedor instanceof Contenedor){
            tipoTransportable = "contenedores";
        }
        if(this.contenedor instanceof Generico){
            tipoTransportable = "genéricos";
        }
        if(this.contenedor instanceof SerVivo){
            tipoTransportable = "seres vivios";
        }
        if(this.contenedor instanceof Toxico){
            tipoTransportable = "productos tóxicos";
        }
        System.out.println(tipoTransportable);
        this.masNombre(tipoTransportable);
    }
```

Comment: Al parecer la expresión de la izquierda no puede ser de tipo `T`. Así que debes cambiar el tipo de la variable `contenedor`. Puede ser de tipo `Object` o `Transportable`

Comment: Si lo que quieres es conocer el tipo con es que se parametriza la clase en tiempo de ejecución lamento decirte que no se puede puesto que Java implementa el mecanismo de genéricos en tiempo de compilación empleando una técnica llamada **Type erasure**. Busca sobre este tema para que entiendas mejor.

Comment: Sí me refiero al tipo con que se parametriza la clase

Comment: Me parece que no estás pensando bien la solución. ¿Qué es lo que estás buscando lograr con este diseño? Que relacion hay entre Contenedor la clase, las interfaces que implementa, y T.

Comment: Seguramente el diseño no sea el mejor ni más eficiente porque es una practica de la universidad de introducción a java con herencias y polimorfismos y el objetivo es reducir el código al máximo. La cuestión es que para asignar un nombre al contenedor necesito saber el tipo de dato con el que se parametriza Contenedor, que puede ser de tipo SerVivo, Generico, Toxico u otro contenedor.

Comment: InstanceOf es una mala práctica. Creo que la mejor solución es usar un patrón Visitor (doble despacho) para conocer la clase hija.